# Sencha CMD 4 unable to package for iOS

Tags: ios, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2.1, sencha-cmd

When I try to package my sencha touch app with

```
sencha app package build iosPack.json
```

I get this error :

```
Unable to load PKCS12 identity
```

Here is my iosPack.json :

```
{   "applicationName":"XXXXX",

    "applicationId":"yyyyyyy",

   "bundleSeedId":"ZZZZZZZZZZ",

   "versionString":"0.1",

   "versionCode":"1",

   "icon": {
    "57":"resources/icons/icon4.png",
    "72":"resources/icons/icon3.png",
    "114":"resources/icons/icon2.png",
    "144":"resources/icons/icon1.png"
   },

   "inputPath":"./",

   "outputPath":"./build/",

   "configuration":"Debug",

   "platform":"iOS",

   "deviceType":"iPhone",

   "certificatePath":"./certifs/ios_development.cer",

   "orientations": [
    "portrait"
   ]
}
```

Where could the problem come from ?

Answer (score 1):

1) Make sure you completed all the steps on generating your certificate correctly.

2) If you used password for the certificate, try to specifty certificate password in your config:

```
 "certificatePath":"./certifs/ios_development.cer",
 "certificatePassword": "Password here",
```

Answer (score 0):

To make it work I converted the cer file to P12 format. The P12 file combines the Apple developer certificate and the associated private key in a single file. The procedure is explained very well in this tutorial :

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/articles/packaging-air-apps-ios.html